# Centering the footer content

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am building a website using wordpress theme and it should be responsive. The problem is with the footer. When you resize the browser window and make it smaller, the content of the footer isn't centered. I think that It's because of the float of each text. How to make that centered when I resize the window?

[WEBSITE](http://svycarsky-dum-responsive.geneweb.cz/)

```
 <div class="site-info">
      <div style="margin:0 auto; width: 75%;">
        <p style="float:left;">&copy; Copyright <?= date('Y'); ?> Hotel Švýcarský Dům</p>
        <div style="float:right;">Naleznete nás na sociálních sítích: 
          <a style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 0 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/gplus.png" /></a>
          <a style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 5px 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/facebook.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- .site-info -->
```

Comment: What do you want to center? The copyright? You are clearly floating elements to the left and the right.

Comment: Add float:none in media queries on p tag (.site-info p)

Comment: `.site-info p{ float: none;} .site-info {text-align: center;}` this is what I put in media queries for max-width: 800px, nothing happens... @nevermind @Data2000

Answer (score 0):

Setting the parent div of the text to 100% width has allowed the text to align in center for me.

```
<div class="site-info">
  <div style="margin:0 auto; width: 75%;">
    <p style="float:left; width:100%">&copy; Copyright <?= date('Y'); ?> Hotel Švýcarský Dům</p>
    <div style="float:right; width:100%">Naleznete nás na sociálních sítích: 
      <a style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 0 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/gplus.png" /></a>
      <a style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 5px 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/facebook.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div><!-- .site-info -->
```

The second div is slightly off center due to the image links within that div.

Answer (score 0):

For the div with the social media links, you could add this to your @media query for everything under 800px:

http://imgur.com/rZz9Och

That should center it like in the image above, if that's what you're going for.